# How can I make the social links in my mobile menu fit together on one line?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been struggling with this all day so I guess I'll ask the community. I am trying to get my social links / icons to fit side-by-side on one line, rather than taking up 5 lines.

It seems that whatever rules I have set for the other list items (which is actually a separate ul) are also being applied to these social links.

Thanks a ton if you can help!
I'll take notes. lol

[Updated Website](https://www.zacheryvaughn.com)

[What I am trying to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35NdB.png)

[What I am currently dealing with.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8Ny9.png)

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
const mobile_menu = document.querySelector('.mobile-nav');

hamburger.addEventListener('click', function () {
    hamburger.classList.toggle('is-active');
    mobile_menu.classList.toggle('is-active');
})
```

```css
:root {
    --light: #FFF;
    --dark: #111;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: roboto-light;
    src: url(fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf);
}
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: roboto-light;
}
.container {
    max-width: 1120px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 12px 10px 12px 20px;
}
nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    background-color: var(--dark);
}
#header-logo {
    width: 42px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
#header-logo:hover {
    opacity: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#header-logo:active {
    opacity: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hamburger {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1; 
    user-select: none;
    appearance: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hamburger span {
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: var(--light);
    z-index: 1;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.hamburger span:nth-child(1) {
    margin-top: 6px;
}
.hamburger.is-active span:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translate(0px, -2px) rotate(45deg);
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    background-color: #757575;
}
.hamburger.is-active span:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(30px);
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    background-color: #757575;
}
.hamburger.is-active span:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translate(-3px, 3px) rotate(-45deg);
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    background-color: #757575;
}
.mobile-nav {
    position: fixed;
    left: 100%;
    min-height: fit-content;
    z-index: 98;
    background-color: #222222;
    padding-top: 66px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.mobile-nav.is-active {
    left: 0;
}
.mobile-nav a {
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    padding: 19px 0px 19px;
    width: 100vw;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #363636;
    background-color: var(--primary);
    color: var(--light);
    text-decoration: none;
}
.mobile-social-links img {
    width: 28px;
}
.mobile-social-links li {
    list-style: none;
    width: 28px;
    display: inline;
}
.menu {
    display: none;
    flex: 1px 1px 0%;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin: 0px -16px;
}
.menu a {
    color: var(--light);
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
    padding: 0px 0px;
}
.menu a.is-active, .menu a:hover {
    color: #757575;
}
.menu a:active{
    color: var(--light);
}
@media (min-width: 780px) {
    .hamburger {
        display: none;
    }
    .menu {
        display: flex;
    }
    .mobile-nav {
        display: none;
    }
    #header-logo {
        width: 80px;
        padding-left: 22px;
    }
    .container {
        padding: 16px 50px 16px 30px;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Zachery Vaughn</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <div class="container">
                    <img src="images/logos/Logo-White-500.png" id="header-logo">
                    <div class="menu">
                        <a href="#">about</a>
                        <a href="#">services</a>
                        <a href="#">portfolio</a>
                        <a href="#">blog</a>
                        <a href="#">contact</a>
                    </div>

                    <button class="hamburger">
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <nav class="mobile-nav">
                <a href="#">about</a>
                <a href="#">services</a>
                <a href="#">portfolio</a>
                <a href="#">blog</a>
                <a href="#">contact</a>
                <div>
                    <ul class="mobile-social-links">
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/social-icons/twitter-icon.png"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/social-icons/linkedin-icon.png"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/social-icons/youtube-icon.png"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/social-icons/facebook-icon.png"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/social-icons/instagram-icon.png"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

        </header>
        <main>

        </main>
        <footer>

        </footer>

        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the element with class .mobile-social-links to display: flex;. There's also a bit of work to do to position them centrally as you're doing some odd stuff with the anchor links but see below. All changes are annotated. There's a bit of animation to do but I'll leave you to sort that out.

Just as an aside you're making life difficult for yourself having two menus, one for desktop and one for mobile. If you can, have one menu but style it for both.

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
const mobile_menu = document.querySelector('.mobile-nav');

hamburger.addEventListener('click', function() {
  hamburger.classList.toggle('is-active');
  mobile_menu.classList.toggle('is-active');
})
```

```css
:root {
  --light: #FFF;
  --dark: #111;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: roboto-light;
  src: url(fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf);
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: roboto-light;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1120px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 12px 10px 12px 20px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: var(--dark);
}

#header-logo {
  width: 42px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#header-logo:hover {
  opacity: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#header-logo:active {
  opacity: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburger {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  user-select: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburger span {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: var(--light);
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.hamburger span:nth-child(1) {
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.hamburger.is-active span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translate(0px, -2px) rotate(45deg);
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  background-color: #757575;
}

.hamburger.is-active span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(30px);
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  background-color: #757575;
}

.hamburger.is-active span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translate(-3px, 3px) rotate(-45deg);
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  background-color: #757575;
}

.mobile-nav {
  position: fixed;
  left: 100%;
  min-height: fit-content;
  z-index: 98;
  background-color: #222222;
  padding-top: 66px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.mobile-nav.is-active {
  left: 0;
}

.mobile-nav a {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding: 19px 0px 19px;
  width: 100vw;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #363636;
  background-color: var(--primary);
  color: var(--light);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.mobile-social-links {
  /* added this */
  display: none;
  padding-block: 19px;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.mobile-nav.is-active .mobile-social-links {
  /*added this */
  display: flex;
}

.mobile-social-links a {
  /* added this */
  display: inline;
  padding: 0;
}

.mobile-social-links img {
  width: 28px;
}

.mobile-social-links li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 28px;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
  flex: 1px 1px 0%;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 0px -16px;
}

.menu a {
  color: var(--light);
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  padding: 0px 0px;
}

.menu a.is-active,
.menu a:hover {
  color: #757575;
}

.menu a:active {
  color: var(--light);
}

@media (min-width: 780px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu {
    display: flex;
  }
  .mobile-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  #header-logo {
    width: 80px;
    padding-left: 22px;
  }
  .container {
    padding: 16px 50px 16px 30px;
    margin: 0px auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="container">
      <img src="images/logos/Logo-White-500.png" id="header-logo">
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="#">about</a>
        <a href="#">services</a>
        <a href="#">portfolio</a>
        <a href="#">blog</a>
        <a href="#">contact</a>
      </div>

      <button class="hamburger">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </button>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <nav class="mobile-nav">
    <a href="#">about</a>
    <a href="#">services</a>
    <a href="#">portfolio</a>
    <a href="#">blog</a>
    <a href="#">contact</a>
    <div>
      <ul class="mobile-social-links">
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="images/social-icons/twitter-icon.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="images/social-icons/linkedin-icon.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="images/social-icons/youtube-icon.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="images/social-icons/facebook-icon.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="images/social-icons/instagram-icon.png"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

I've also done a version with grid but it means only one menu is needed. See below:

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');

hamburger.addEventListener('click', function() {
  hamburger.classList.toggle('is-active');
  menu.classList.toggle('is-active');
})
```

```css
:root {
  --light: #FFF;
  --dark: #111;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: roboto-light;
  src: url(fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf);
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: roboto-light;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1120px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 12px 10px 12px 20px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: var(--dark);
}

#header-logo {
  width: 42px;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#header-logo:hover {
  opacity: 50%;
}

.hamburger {
  grid-area: hamburger;
  justify-self: end;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburger span {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  background-color: var(--light);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
}

.hamburger.is-active span {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  background-color: #757575;
}

.hamburger span:nth-child(1) {
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.hamburger.is-active span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translate(0px, -2px) rotate(45deg);
}

.hamburger.is-active span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(30px);
}

.hamburger.is-active span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translate(-3px, 3px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: fit-content(0) 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "icon hamburger" "menu menu";
}

.image-container {
  grid-area: icon;
}

.menu {
  grid-area: menu;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #222222;
  transition: max-height 1s, margin-top 1s;
}

.menu a {
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--light);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.4s;
  padding: 19px 0;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #363636;
}

.menu.is-active {
  max-height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.menu a:hover {
  color: #757575;
}

.menu a:active {
  color: var(--light);
}

.mobile-social-links {
  padding: 19px;
}

.mobile-social-links>ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.mobile-social-links a {
  padding: 0;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 780px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu {
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex-direction: row;
    background: none;
    display: flex;
    max-height: initial;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .menu a {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1rem;
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  .mobile-social-links {
    display: none;
  }
  #header-logo {
    width: 80px;
    padding-left: 22px;
  }
  .container {
    grid-template-areas: "icon menu";
    padding: 16px 50px 16px 30px;
    margin: 0px auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/500/500" id="header-logo">
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <a href="#">about</a>
      <a href="#">services</a>
      <a href="#">portfolio</a>
      <a href="#">blog</a>
      <a href="#">contact</a>
      <div class="mobile-social-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hamburger">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Wow, you are totally right... Why am I using two separate menus. Thanks for that suggestion, I'll redo it. Quick question, to restyle the same menu, would all of those rules be in a media query?

Comment: Your solution worked, you're a wizard, thank you. Will remember this for next time.

Comment: You're very welcome dude. I'd style them all with a media query. I'll fire up an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding display: flex to the ul with the .mobile-social-links class.

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
const mobile_menu = document.querySelector('.mobile-nav');

hamburger.addEventListener('click', function () {
    hamburger.classList.toggle('is-active');
    mobile_menu.classList.toggle('is-active');
})
```

```css
:root {
    --light: #FFF;
    --dark: #111;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: roboto-light;
    src: url(fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf);
}
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: roboto-light;
}
.container {
    max-width: 1120px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 12px 10px 12px 20px;
}
nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    background-color: var(--dark);
}
#header-logo {
    width: 42px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
#header-logo:hover {
    opacity: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#header-logo:active {
    opacity: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hamburger {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1; 
    user-select: none;
    appearance: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hamburger span {
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: var(--light);
    z-index: 1;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.hamburger span:nth-child(1) {
    margin-top: 6px;
}
.hamburger.is-active span:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translate(0px, -2px) rotate(45deg);
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    background-color: #757575;
}
.hamburger.is-active span:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(30px);
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    background-color: #757575;
}
.hamburger.is-active span:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translate(-3px, 3px) rotate(-45deg);
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    background-color: #757575;
}
.mobile-nav {
    position: fixed;
    left: 100%;
    min-height: fit-content;
    z-index: 98;
    background-color: #222222;
    padding-top: 66px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.mobile-nav.is-active {
    left: 0;
}
.mobile-nav a {
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    padding: 19px 0px 19px;
    width: 100vw;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #363636;
    background-color: var(--primary);
    color: var(--light);
    text-decoration: none;
}
.mobile-social-links img {
    width: 28px;
}
.mobile-social-links li {
    list-style: none;
    width: 28px;
    display: inline;
}
.menu {
    display: none;
    flex: 1px 1px 0%;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin: 0px -16px;
}
.menu a {
    color: var(--light);
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
    padding: 0px 0px;
}
.menu a.is-active, .menu a:hover {
    color: #757575;
}
.menu a:active{
    color: var(--light);
}
ul.mobile-social-links{
    display: flex;
}

@media (min-width: 780px) {
    .hamburger {
        display: none;
    }
    .menu {
        display: flex;
    }
    .mobile-nav {
        display: none;
    }
    #header-logo {
        width: 80px;
        padding-left: 22px;
    }
    .container {
        padding: 16px 50px 16px 30px;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Zachery Vaughn</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <div class="container">
                    <img src="images/logos/Logo-White-500.png" id="header-logo">
                    <div class="menu">
                        <a href="#">about</a>
                        <a href="#">services</a>
                        <a href="#">portfolio</a>
                        <a href="#">blog</a>
                        <a href="#">contact</a>
                    </div>

                    <button class="hamburger">
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <nav class="mobile-nav">
                <a href="#">about</a>
                <a href="#">services</a>
                <a href="#">portfolio</a>
                <a href="#">blog</a>
                <a href="#">contact</a>
                <div>
                    <ul class="mobile-social-links">
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/social-icons/twitter-icon.png"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/social-icons/linkedin-icon.png"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/social-icons/youtube-icon.png"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/social-icons/facebook-icon.png"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/social-icons/instagram-icon.png"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

        </header>
        <main>

        </main>
        <footer>

        </footer>

        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The rules are still being applied to your links in the other ul as they still match.

I.e. Your mobile social links are still being given the width of 100vw because they are still  elements within the 'mobile-nav' element. You'd need the rules below to take higher precedence, So where you've applied 'width: 28px;' to the '.mobile-social-links li' you'd want to apply it to the '.mobile-social-links li a' so it can overwrite the initial css

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).